# Iterate over arrays in liquid templates

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I know I can iterate over arrays in liquid template with this code:

```
{% for item in myarray %}
    <p>{{ item.label }}</p>
```

But how can I get the index of my item within the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the ["Liquid for Designers"](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) section on liquid's github...

```
forloop.length      # => length of the entire for loop
forloop.index       # => index of the current iteration
forloop.index0      # => index of the current iteration (zero based)
forloop.rindex      # => how many items are still left?
forloop.rindex0     # => how many items are still left? (zero based)
forloop.first       # => is this the first iteration?
forloop.last        # => is this the last iteration?
```

All of these are helper variables for `for` loops. You will find these two most useful...

```
forloop.index       # => index of the current iteration
forloop.index0      # => index of the current iteration (zero based)
```